# How do i default the grid view date to today

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to format the date field in a grid view to NOW, or getdate .
The example below shows the dataformatstring formatting the date, but how do I default the date to getdate

```
        <asp:BoundField ApplyFormatInEditMode="True" DataField="DateReceived" 
                DataFormatString="{0:MM-dd-yyyy}" HeaderText="DateReceived" HtmlEncode="False" 
                SortExpression="DateReceived" />
```

Comment: The source data must be the date of today, not the GridView.

Comment: Correct, since it is a bound control you need to bind it to what you want to see in code.

Comment: The source data shows this as blank until a product has been received, then I want the only entry option to be the date it is received as in NOW. I do not want them to accidently put a date prior to NOW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use a `BoundField` you need to make sure the source data is todays date. But you can easily show todays date with a `TemplateField`.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

       <asp:BoundField DataField="myOtherColumn1" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="myOtherColumn2" />

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```